# iOS 7 : UITextField inputView issue when set to UIDatePicker

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, autolayout, uidatepicker

I have set `UIDatePicker`as `TextField`'s inputView. When `TextField` becomes `firstResponder` the first time, `UIDatePicker`'s height is smaller than standard height as shown below :

[image]

Then after any time `TextField` becomes `firstResponder`, `UIDatePicker`'s height is correct as shown below :

[image]

This issue is not there when I run app on iOS 6 simulator, but only there when run on iOS 7.

Any idea why is this? Can it be related to auto layout?

Comment: No, Its not related to autolayout. I think you have set frame of date picker anywhere that's why its happning.

Comment: put  code of textFieldShouldBeginEditing..

Comment: this is not a autolayout mistake, u made a mistake manually  in the textFieldShouldBeginEditing method,

Comment: I am not sure but it seems that you have set a UIView that contain UIDatePicker & UIToolBar in UItextField's input view..

if yes then please try...
UIDatePicker as inputView.
UIToolBar as inputAccessoryView

Comment: @RajeshChoudhary No I have not used UIView as container

Comment: @DharmbirChoudhary No I have not set frame. It is in storyboard.

Comment: @iPatel I have not implemented `textFieldShouldBeginEditing` method.

Comment: @Geek I seems its manual mistake.

Comment: @DharmbirChoudhary Its something else. When I add DatePicker to storyboard, neither do I change its height nor it allows me to change. Also when TextField becomes first responder the second time or later, it displays correct hight of DatePicker. How this resizing happens?

Comment: @Geek You knw can't find out this prblm without see your code.

Comment: @DharmbirChoudhary I added code. Please check out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had added `UIDatePicker` in storyboard. Now, I have solved the issue by creating `UIDatePicker` through code and setting it as inputView. I am still looking for an answer that explains the reason why it did not work with storyboard. I will change accepted answer if I get any.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a "spring issue"...
I've solved with this settings:

[image]

Take a look at the Autoresizings...